# Should I only be using one or multiple instances of python's secrets.SystemRandom() class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, random, trng

I am trying to generate random numbers securely and I found the secrets module, apparently the only way to generate random numbers is to have an instance of the `secrets.SystemRandom` class, but now I am confused, should I be using one or multiple instances of it for generating 17 random numbers in different and completely unrelated places?

EDIT 1: Documentation for secrets.SystemRandom() https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom

EDIT 2: The docs are from here https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html

EDIT 3: After using https://grep.app/ and finding https://github.com/pyradius/pyrad/blob/master/pyrad/packet.py I think I only need to use one instance of the class, I will use it, if this is wrong, please leave a comment or an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should I be using one or multiple instances of it for generating 17
> random numbers in different and completely unrelated places?

You only need one instance of `random.SystemRandom`. Create the instance and reuse it.

```
>>> from random import SystemRandom
>>> rgenerator = SystemRandom()
>>> rint = rgenerator.randint
>>> rint(0, 10)
6
```

Comment: Check `EDIT 3`, I figured it out :) also I meant the secrets lib but it's just an alias to random if we're talking about SystemRandom :)

Comment: Glad that you did! I know that you meant `secrets` but as you just pointed out `random.SystemRandom` and `secrets.SystemRandom` are aliases of one another.

Answer (score 0):

> now I am confused, should I be using one or multiple instances of it for generating 17 random numbers in different and completely unrelated places?

It doesn't matter, because as noted in the documentation `SystemRandom` has no internal state of its own, it just calls the OS' random data source (via `os.urandom`). So using 15 different instances or one has the same result (though the former wastes a bit more memory).

So you can do whatever you find clearer, it has no real technical or correctness bearing (incidentally it's quite frustrating that `secrets` does have an internal `SystemRandom` instance which it doesn't expose).